# Calculating sum of parts of column based on another column using QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I would like to calculate the sum of values in one column, based on values in another column. To illustrate my question I uploaded the picture below. The second column consists of zipcodes, the third total sales. I would like to know what the total sales per zipcode are? So in this case:

What is the sum of column three for column two's value `1023`? Output then should be `4 (0+1+1+2+0)`. The sum for `1024` then should be 11,5 following the same logic.

As this is quite a large dataset I would like to have the QGIS field calculator (or any other tool) calculate a new field which states the total sales in the zipcode. So far I can't seem to get it working and was hoping someone here could help me.

As you can see I have some missing values, is this a problem in calculation? Perhaps good to mention is that it is a table.

[image: Example]

Comment: should be 3 (0+1+1+2+0) ?? really?

Answer (score 25):

**Update: QGIS 2.18 (07/07/2017):**

In the **Field Calculator**, you can use the *Aggregate* function `sum` which allows you to sum the values of a column based on an expression. You can also, optionally, group and filter features for summation. So in your field calculator, you could simply use:

```
sum( "Sum", "Sales")
```

Which does exactly the same as the method using the **GroupStats** plugin.

---

---

**Original post: 02/03/2016**

Use the **GroupStats** plugin which you may need to download from *Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*.

Here's an example layer using some of the attributes you have shown:

[image: Layer]

So let's:

1. Run the **GroupStats** plugin, select the relevant fields for summing (`Sales` for rows; `Sum` for values) and then click *Calculate*. You should see the results showing the sum of each sale:

   [image: GroupStats plugin]
2. Save the results as a .csv file from the GroupStats toolbar:

   [image: Export to csv]
3. Import the .csv file back into QGIS either by dragging it to the interface or from the toolbar:

   *Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer* (*note that the values are separated by semi-colons*)
4. Do a **Joins** with the shapefile and the .csv file, matching the `Sales` fields:

   [image: Joins]
5. The shapefile should now contain the sum values from the .csv file:

   [image: Results]

You could, if you wish, proceed to use the `Save As...` option on the shapefile and save it as a new one to keep the joined fields.

Comment: It would be helpful if the field calculator component of this answer included the SQL lines which group and/or filter. @Joseph

Comment: @eyerah - The expression `sum( "Sum", "Sales")` uses `"Sales"` as a group filter, if that is what you mean?

Comment: Oh. I see that now.  That is what I meant.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

If you update to the very latest QGIS version 2.14, you can use virtual layers making a sql statement like:

```
SELECT "MYTABLE"."MYID", Sum("MYTABLE"."SALES")  AS zip_sale /*:int*/
FROM "MYTABLE"
GROUP BY "MYTABLE"."ZIPCODE"
```

The UI looks like:

[image]

You can also use the DB manager, where you have a query builder behind the sql button:

[image]

The MYID column can be used to join the summed sales back to the main table. The join tab is under tabel properties.

Take a look at the [QGIS visual changelog](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog214/) under `Feature: Virtual layers`

Answer (score 6):

A way of doing this is the following:

- In the attribute table, choose select by feature. Type "column-name" = 1023. All fields with the value 1023 are selected.
- Go to vector tools --> Analysing tools --> basic statistics. Choose your layer and the column with the sales. Make sure to check the "selected values only" check-box. The sum will be displayed in the result window. You have to write it down ;)
- repeat the steps for every zip-code

Comment: P.S. Missing values are no problem.

Comment: This is a simple and well-working approach. However it might be very time consuming when processing a large data set as Ammar mentioned...