# Summing attribute based on another attribute in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I have an attribute table for buildings in my city. The important fields are Output Area, where the building is located, and TotalArea, a calculated sum of the floorspace of that building.

What I'd like to do is find the total area of all buildings in each output area, and add that data to the output area table.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Field calculator: Calculate sum of parts of column, based on another column](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183037/field-calculator-calculate-sum-of-parts-of-column-based-on-another-column).

Comment: This post is also similar: 
"Getting tabular statistics from table using QGIS?": http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43037/getting-tabular-statistics-from-table-using-qgis
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43037/getting-tabular-statistics-from-table-using-qgis