# Compute fractions of feature in grid cell

Tags: qgis, python, overlapping-features

I have a shapefile containing features (line) and I have a UTM grid in the same area. The feature is a coastline with different types. 
Now I would like to produce the length of coastline and the length of each type within each UTM grid cell. 
I prefer using Python or QGIS/SAGA GIS.

I found the post on how to create my UTM grid and I have the shapefile but how do I compute the fractions?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do the following (assuming your UTM grid are polygons, if not then you can convert it using the **Lines to polygons** tool):

1. Run the **Intersection** tool with the line layer as *Input layer* and your polygon grid layer as the *Intersect* layer. This should output your line layer but split into each grid.
2. Run the **Field Calculator** on the output and create a new field with the expression `$length` to calculate the length of coast line within each grid.
3. Run the **GroupStats** plugin to calculate the *sum* of the length for each type of coast line (similar method as described in this post: [Calculating sum of parts of column based on another column using QGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183037/calculating-sum-of-parts-of-column-based-on-another-column-using-qgis-field-calc/183060#183060)).